# Input Box Border Missing when adding bootsrap input-group class

Tags: bootstrap-4

When I add the input-group class to a textbox, the border around the textbox disappears. If i remove the class the textbox works fine.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="input-group">
               <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text">Find</span>
                   </div>
                  </div>
            </div>
         </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: not able to reproduce, also you are missing `"` in `class="container-fluid`

Comment: that was just a typo, I do have the " in my code.

Comment: Please edit your question and show us what is actually a problem

Comment: that was the problem, but thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Only thing I added was the button div in my input group and  now it's working, don't know what the problem was.

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <div class="input-group">
                       <input type="text" class="form-control" />
                        <div class="input-group-append"><span class="input-group-text">X</span></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                            <input class="btn" type="submit" value="Find" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
```